# Running Google Cloud SDK Shell command on PC startup

Tags: sdk, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

I have an excel file in a Google Cloud storage bucket which updates everyday. I found that I am able to download the updated file everyday by running this code on the Google Cloud SDK Shell:

`gsutil cp gs://bot-example/Koersen.xlsx C:\\Users\\wmjdo\\Documents\\Koersen.xlsx`

I was wondering if there is a way for me to tell the SDK Shell to run this script whenever I start up my computer. I'm not sure if this can be done with the Shell directly but maybe there is a way for me to write a python script to run this command which I can then set to run when I start my PC.

Any input or advice is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: on windows you can create a bat or a powershell file and run it at the start up. There is no relation with Google Cloud here!

Comment: Do I not need the GC shell to make contact with the GC bucket? I thought that my pc needed to make a connection with Google through the SDK.

Comment: No! Install the gcloud SDK, login into it (gcloud auth login). Then your credentials are stored. When your pc start, simply perform a gsutil ... it will use your already stored credential. Have a try on it and let me know

Comment: Oh my god I have been stuck on this for so long... Turns out, I indeed do not need the GC SDK Shell. I just needed to authorize my project in the cmd with ```gsutil config```. Thanks for the huge tip @guillaumeblaquiere ! I am now trying to create a batch file that runs the code I used in my initial question. In my understanding a batch file can be used to run commands in the cmd window and they can be put in a 'startup' folder. Not sure yet how it all works exactly. But I'm getting closer and closer to my goal, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! I didn't have to use the Google Cloud SDK Shell. Instead, I just needed to authotize my cmd to be able to connect with the GC storage. To do this, I ran the following code in the cmd: `gsutil config`. I had to answer some safety questions like typing in my project-ID which can be found in the GC console. After the authorization I created a batch file and ran the following code:

```
c:\
gsutil cp gs://bot-example/Koersen.xlsx C:\\Users\\wmjdo\\Documents\\Koersen.xlsx
```

I then proceeded to move the batch file to the windows startup folder which executes the batch file everytime windows is booted up. The startup folder can be found by using the shortkey windows+r and then typing shell:startup.

Thanks for helping me out !